# Locking MySQL tables not working in Tornado

Tags: mysql, locking, tornado

I have this code:

```
# Retreive the users that can obtain permission on the network except the admin
self.lock_tables("read", ['nets_permissions as n', 'users as u'])
usrs = self.db.query("SELECT distinct u.id FROM users as u \
        left outer join nets_permissions as n on u.id = n.user_id \
        where u.id not in \
        (select users.id from users left outer join nets_permissions \
        on users.id = nets_permissions.user_id \
        where nets_permissions.network_id=%s and nets_permissions.perm=3)", netid)
self.unlock_tables()
```

But I obtain this error in the Tornado screen:

> File "./wsn.py", line 571, in get
>       where nets_permissions.network_id=%s and nets_permissions.perm=3)", netid)
>       raise errorclass, errorvalue OperationalError: (1100, "Table 'users' was not locked with LOCK TABLES")

Where is the error?

Comment: `lock_tables` looks like the culprit; it also looks like it's your code, not Tornado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
# Retreive the users that can obtain permission on the network except the admin
    self.lock_tables("read", ['nets_permissions as n', 'users as u', 'nets_permissions as m', 'users as v'])
    usrs = self.db.query("SELECT distinct u.id FROM users as u \
                          left outer join nets_permissions as n on u.id = n.user_id \
                          where u.id not in \
                          (select v.id from users as v left outer join nets_permissions as m \
                          on v.id = m.user_id \
                          where m.network_id=%s and m.perm=3)", netid)
    self.unlock_tables()
```